# executing python file in terminal - socket.error: no socket could be created

Tags: python

```
(webgame)Benjamins-MacBook:webgame test$ python bin/app.py
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/app.py", line 21, in <module>
app.run()
File "/Users/test/Pythonprojects/webgame/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py",    line 310, in run
return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
File "/Users/test/Pythonprojects/webgame/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/wsgi.py", line   54, in runwsgi
return httpserver.runsimple(func, validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, '')))
File "/Users/test/Pythonprojects/webgame/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/httpserver.py", line 148, in runsimple
server.start()
File "/Users/test/Pythonprojects/webgame/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1753, in start
raise socket.error(msg)
socket.error: No socket could be created
```

What in gods name does this mean...  Also, I'm pretty sure the last time I ran python bin/app.py, it worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
python bin/app.py 3030
```

There might be another server running on 8080.

Comment: that works!  should I be concerned about this though?  Also localhost:8080 never worked either.  I have no firewall turned on or anything like that. @Rohit im trying to chat with you right now

Comment: to find out what server is running on 8080 port, you can go to http://localhost:8080 in your browser.